# Email Background image is not displayed in outlook desktop application - office 365

Tags: php, html, email, outlook, background-image

I am Sending email form php code and my email message body is HTML

```
$emailBody=<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#textDiv{
    background-image: url("appreciation-'.$imageId.'.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;width:595px;height: 842px;color: white;float: center;
    }
#p1{
    padding-top: 420px;padding-left: 50px;width: 500px;font-size: large;
}
#p2{
    padding-top: 30px;padding-left: 50px;width: 500px;font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center> 
<div id="textDiv"  align="center" style="font-family: cursive; text-align:center;">
        <p id="p1">Hi '.$actReciverName.', you have received Kudos from '.$senderName.' </p>
        <p id="p2"><i><u>"'.$comment.'"</u></i></p> 
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

once the email is sent background image is not displaying in outlook desktop app, but its working fine in Outlook Web mail, how to make it visible in desktop outlook application

Thanks in advance for support

Comment: This may help you out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: the short answer is, it is not possible to display bg img in outlook

Comment: Pretty sure this doesn't work without errors, where are your quotes? `$emailBody=<!DOCTYPE html>...`

Answer (score 0):

HTML messages are rendered by Word in Outlook, and Word does not support background images. Try to create a table and set its background image.

Comment: Even table backgrounds are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

The other answer isn't entirely correct, and those comments are misleading (at best).  Background images do work using [bulletproof backgrounds](https://backgrounds.cm/), which utilize VML to create your background.

I just coded an email using transparent gradients as background images inside a hybrid design.

The only client I haven't been able to get this to work 100% for is Dark Mode in version 16 of Outlook for Office 365, but it is still present, just that version of Outlook fills transparencies as white.  Many eCommerce clients won't care at all about users who use Dark Mode in Outlook for 365 (v16), but I suggest you check with your Email/marketing team to find out before deciding.